# How to fill gaps in data based on previous values

Tags: python, pandas

Table 1 represents the format of my raw data. The dataset was prepared in such a way that the name of a variable 1 is only mentioned for the first observation. I am exploring the dataset and would like to report the count of certain features grouped by the first variable. to achieve this I would have to transform my data into the second table (Output).

How can I achieve this with pandas?

[image: Format of the data][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWwhC.png)

Comment: Hi, can you please copy and paste the data as text, no images please(we cant copy them)

Comment: also try `df['Var 1']= df['Var 1'].ffill()`

Comment: Thanks for the link, that solved it. I keep your feedback in mind for future posts.

Comment: @anky_91 What would be the best format to share the data I posted? I can't seem to make markdown tables in the editor.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found in the pandas documentation under **[Upsampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/api.html#upsampling)**. The method used is called *ffill()* and is used as such:
    df.ffill()